# Caption parbox 6.0 pt too wide

Tags: color, captions, boxes

For my listings, I use this caption setup:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
```

For each listing, `pdflatex` warns me:

```
Overfull \hbox (6.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 129--129
```

In the PDF, one can easily see that it is indeed too wide there:

[image]

And a close up:

[image]

How can I get this to match exactly the width of the remaining contents?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `\colorbox` adds some space before and after the text inside it; this space is `\fboxsep` wide; so

```
\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}
```

will do. You might also load the `calc` package and then write the same in the perhaps more natural syntax

```
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1#2#3}}
```

Comment: Awesome, now it looks really neat!

Comment: Since v3.3 of the `caption` package the option `box=colorbox` is available to make things easier. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88206/2574