# Exclude listings from LoL

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

Is there a way to exclude a specific listing from being printed in the LoL? I put one in a figure environment for the sake of not being printed on two seperate pages. But now I have the figure as well as the listing in the toc

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listing]

\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Update:**

I used this to have a special listing caption for all *real* listings.

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bf\sffamily\smaller#1#2#3}}\vskip-1pt}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
```

Comment: Don't use `\caption`? And why do you use figure to avoid a page break. Maybe a minipage is better for your situation.

Comment: Which one do you want to remove: the listing or the figure caption? Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of your current setup?

Comment: I want to remove the listing entry. Just provided a MWE. I decided to put this in a figure also because I used tikz to annote some things in the listing.

Comment: Do you really need two captions? If not, just do as knut said, and remove `\caption{Figure}`. Otherwise: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43995/ignore-figure-for-list-of-figures

Comment: I didn't provide a listing caption, but I need the figure caption.

Comment: Yes you did: `\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listing]`

Comment: Mh, yes I did this in the MWE because I thought it's not important whether I declare a caption or not. In my real document, I didn't provide a caption. Nevertheless I have a toc entry... ?!

Comment: If you remove the `[caption=Listing]` option, you don't obtain an entry in the LoL (and that's not a joke)...

Comment: I know it's not a joke, but I *do* get an entry. I updated the post. I think it's related to this. I know it's maybe a bit too localized, but I just realized that and tomorrow is the deadline :( Sorry and thanks for your help.

Comment: `[caption=Listing]` goes into the List of Listings (LoL), and `\caption{Figure}` goes into the List of Figures (LoF). In your MWE you do not even have a `\tableofcontents`, nevertheless you have an entry in the Table of Contents (“ToC”)? Remove `[caption=Listing]` to get rid of the LoL entry, remove `\caption{Figure}` or use `\caption[]{Figure}` to remove the LoF entry. And by the way, your MWE misses `\usepackage{caption}` and at least a definition of `\smaller` (but that’s not the point).

Comment: If you want a caption for the Listing but not an entry in the LoL, you can try the environment option `nolol`: `\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listing,nolol]`. Or: `\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[]Listing}]` which hides the Listing number _and_ doesn’t produce a LoL entry.

Comment: Thank you so much :) `nolol` worked for me. It was strange, because before there was actually no caption printed, but I got a `.` in the LoL. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we already figured out in a lengthy comment discussion:

- **ToC:** Table of Contents (`\tableofcontents`)
- **LoF:** List of Figures (`\listoffigures`)
- **LoL:** List of Listings (`\listoflistings`)

Either way, you are looking for the `lstlistings` option **`nolol`**.

If you additionally want no Listings number to be applied you have to use `caption={[]<caption>}` (with or without `nolol`).

#### Reference

- The [`listings` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf), section 4.9 “Captions”, page 32

### Not related, but noteworthy

Your `\parbox` exceeds the line width by `6pt`. (You get a overfull hbox message!) The reason is that the `\parbox` has a small paddings to its contents, `3pt` on each side (even vertically). This is removed by using `\linewidth-2\fboxsep` in the definition.

And as you may have noticed, I also changed `\textwidth` to `\linewidth`.

#### References

- [Caption parbox 6.0 pt too wide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37907/caption-parbox-6-0-pt-too-wide)
- [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\bf\sffamily\small #1#2#3}}\vskip-1pt}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents \lstlistoflistings \listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listing,nolol]

\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```